# What is additionalparams for?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, jscript

I have inherited some JScript written for CRM 4.

I am trying to remove the IE-specific and deprecated bits.

I have encountered this:

```
document.FilterLookup = function (source, target) {
    if (IsNull(source) || IsNull(target)) { return; }

    var name = IsNull(source.getValue()) ? '' : source.getValue()[0].name;

    target.additionalparams = 'search=' + name;
}
```

Custom Code Validation Tool complains about ".additionalparams".

I've googled a lot but can't even work out what .additionalparams is doing let alone what I could replace it with.

I hope that you do.

Comment: It looks like it is adding additional parameters to the Query String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

additionalparams is not supported in CRM 2011.
Check here for more info:
http://advantageworks.blogspot.ca/2008/02/pseudo-filtered-lookup-dialog-in.html

I suggest you re-write the code using the new 2011 custom filtered lookup feature.

Check here for information on how to implement filtered lookups in CRM 2011

http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmpowerobjects/archive/2013/08/05/creating-a-custom-filtered-lookup-in-crm-2011.aspx#.UieQRTZ2e24

Comment: It looks a lot more work in CRM 2011. Do I really have to build big XML strings simply to alter the default lookup screen?

Comment: This might be relevant too: http://crmconsultancy.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/filtered-lookups-in-crm-2011/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the lookup?  What does the lookup need to be filtered on? You may not need code at all.. If the lookup needs to be filtered based on the value of another field use [Related Records Filtering](http://rashans.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/crm-2011-implementing-dependent-lookups/)